# Implementing own user registration and authentication with IdentityServer

Tags: identityserver3

I have a database with users, how would I start creating a custom implementation of my users with IdentityServer? All the examples I have seen use the `InMemoryUser` that are hard coded with values.

Can one follow [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService) as a guide line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, That is a good point.In IndentityServer v3 there is an interface(`IUserService`) to interact with user store. You can implement the interface using MembershipReboot  or Asp.net Identity.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I have managed to implement the UserService successfully.

Comment: If you get your answer. Please mark it and answered :)